# Variáveis do Mysql não funcionam com mysqli_fetch_array() do php

Tags: php, mysql

Defini duas varáveis no MySQL para simplificar mais uma Query que pretendo implantar no meu sistema. Utilizando esse comando direto no SGBD, ele funciona muito bem, porém, ao querer usar como uma query string no meu script php, ele não funciona. Dá erro na função mysqli_fetch_array(conexao, queryString). O que poderia ser?

```
<?php 

$str = " /*Defino as variáveis*/    
SET @totVenda := (SELECT SUM(total) FROM tb_produto_item_estoque_saida); 
SET @totPorcentagem := (SELECT SUM((ROUND((total/@totVenda*100),2))) FROM tb_produto_item_estoque_saida); 

/*Query principal onde faço uso das variáveis*/
SELECT i.id, i.nome, SUM(ies.quantidade) AS quantidade, ies.valor, SUM(ies.total) AS total, 

@totVenda AS TotalGeral, 

SUM((ROUND((ies.total/@totVenda*100),2))) AS porcentagem

FROM tb_produto_item AS i 
LEFT JOIN tb_produto_item_estoque_entrada AS iee ON i.id = iee.idItem
LEFT JOIN tb_produto_item_estoque_saida AS ies ON i.id = ies.idItem 

GROUP BY i.id
ORDER BY porcentagem DESC";

$query = mysqli_query($conexao->conecta(),$str);

while($retorno = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  //Listaria o resultado aqui! 
}

?>
```

Agradeço desde já! Boa semana! :)

Comment: $query = mysqli_query($conexao,$str); retira a função conecta()

Comment: Fabio, por que você não cria uma procedure no seu banco? Isso vai melhorar o tempo de execução e deixa a aplicação mais rápida, com a procedure criada, no PHP você só vai precisar chamar ela e pronto.

Comment: Faça separadamente a chamada de cada linha, as variáveis persistem na sessão. Por padrao você não consegue fazer multiquery com o `mysql_query`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que são *queries* separadas:

1. `SET @totVenda := (SELECT SUM(total) FROM tb_produto_item_estoque_saida);`
2. `SET @totPorcentagem := (SELECT SUM((ROUND((total/@totVenda*100),2))...`
3. `SELECT i.id, i.nome, SUM(ies.quantidade) AS quantidade, ies.valor, ...`

E a função `mysqli_query`, até por uma questão de segurança, não executa uma *string* neste formato.

Se quer mais de uma *query* deve usar essa função:

```
mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)
```

> https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.multi-query.php

Ou executar separado:

```
mysql_query($link, "SET @totVenda := (SELECT SUM(total) FROM  ... );"); 
mysql_query($link, "SET @totPorcentagem := (SELECT ... uma por linha ... );")
mysql_query($link, "SELECT i.id, i.nome, SUM(ies.quantidade) AS ... ");
```

Desde que você use o mesmo `$link` em todas funciona, pois as variáveis são retidas por conexão.

Comment: Estava fazendo uns testes para ver o que seria melhor... o multi_query ou várias querys... em termo de desempenho não muda muito.. é quase igual ambos os casos... Não consigo entender a vantagem de usar o multi_query além de poder fazer várias consultas ao mesmo tempo! =/

Comment: @AndreiCoelho não é questão de vantagem, e sim do que é mais adequado para cada situação. Não muda muito se você testar localmente. Se pegar qualquer tipo de latência de rede, por exemplo em servidores separados, as queries "avulsas" vão multiplicar o atraso a cada requisição, o multi_query vai mandar de uma vez só. Fora a questão da segurança de você ter certeza que só vai permitir multiplas queries somente onde realmente definiu, minimizando a area para injeção de determinados tipos de comando.

Comment: Muito obrigado Bacco por esse comentário! Vou dar mais uma aprofundada